# Neo4j internals: inUse

Tags: neo4j

What does the `inUse` bit do? Is it a marker for deleted items so they can be lazily reused?

Referencing page 12 of http://www.slideshare.net/thobe/an-overview-of-neo4j-internals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably best to ping Tobias directly on Twitter @thobe :)